# ajax post to mvc controller, all values are null

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I am building an order tracking app using ASP.Net Core MVC. I have a table displaying all of the orders and am trying to implement inline editing of three of the columns. I am trying to post the edited values to my controller using ajax but the controller does not seem to be receiving anything.

```
var orderUpdate = {};
orderUpdate.Id = row.find(".Id").html();
orderUpdate.Responsible = row.find(".Responsible").find("span").html();
orderUpdate.Comments = row.find(".Comments").find("span").html();
orderUpdate.Promise_Date = row.find(".Promise_Date").find("span").html();
console.log(orderUpdate);
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/Orders/UpdateOrder",
     data: '{order:' + JSON.stringify(orderUpdate) + '}',
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
});
```

Here is the method in my controller, the console.writeline prints 0 for the Id and nothing for the other attributes at the moment when I edit values.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateOrder(Order x)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x.Id);
    Console.WriteLine(x.Responsible);
    Console.WriteLine(x.Comments);
    Console.WriteLine(x.Promise_Date);

    //Order updatedOrder = (from o in _context.Orders where o.Id == order.Id select o).FirstOrDefault();
    //updatedOrder.Responsible = order.Responsible;  
    _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

And theses are the relevant bits of my model

```
 public class Order
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Responsible { get; set; }
        public string Comments { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime? Promise_Date { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you want to pass json data to controller,you need to use `[FromBody]`.

Here is a demo worked:

controller:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult UpdateOrder()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UpdateOrder([FromBody]Order order)
        {

            return new EmptyResult();
        }
```

View:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "UpdateOrder";
}

<h1>UpdateOrder</h1>
<button onclick="submit()">submit</button>
@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function submit() {
            var orderUpdate = {};
            orderUpdate.Id = 1;
            orderUpdate.Responsible = "Responsible";
            orderUpdate.Comments = "Comments";
            var order = JSON.stringify(orderUpdate);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Test/UpdateOrder",
                data: order,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The post body is wrong.

```
data: '{order:' + JSON.stringify(orderUpdate) + '}'
```

You will get a json string: `{order:{}}`. It's not a JSON string but a JS object.

You should serialize the whole object with `JSON.stringify({order: orderUpdate})`